# Who pushed Kallystine's face into her youth mixture?

Tags: kencyrath

In P.C. Hodgell's *Seeker's Mask*, minor antagonist Kallystine has been developing a mixture that is meant to transfer youth from one person to another via contact, but so far it only ages people who contact it without a way to transfer the youth. When she has Jame under her power, she plans to test the potion on Jame, but then:

> "Ah . . . oooo!" said the wind, and sucked the drapes out the embrasures into the night. The candle flames leaped and died. In the sudden, rushing darkness which followed, a strong hand grabbed Kallystine by the hair and thrust her downward into icy liquid. She reared back, sputtering, clawing at her eyes. Her face felt strange.

A subsequent scene is from Jame's point of view, and it sounds like she's innocent.

> The moment the candles blew out, Jame whisked herself through a window into the night, as handily as anyone could whose legs were practically bound together by a tight under-skirt. Jorin scrambled after her. They paused outside, listening to the commotion behind them.

Kallystine assumes Jame attacked her, but I don't think the evidence supports it. So who was it? Was it one of the Bashtiri assassins later revealed to be prowling the halls invisibly? The Kendar maid whose braid Kallystine demanded and then tossed away and who has apparently been subjected to the experiments? The last seems most likely except that the Kendar are bonded to the Highborn in a way that makes it very hard for them to act against their masters.

I'm only partway through my reread-through, so it could be this is answered later, but I'm posting this here while it's fresh in my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the question to the Kencyrath mailing list, and received confirmation from the author after someone else posted their guess that it was the maid.

> Yes, it was the maid.
>
> Pat
>
> On Feb 3, 2021, at 8:00 AM, Tashina Peplinski alith7@hotmail.com wrote:
>
> It was Kallystine’s maid.  At least, that’s how I always felt by the implications of the way the maid was acting towards her, and she had JUST cut off the braid that evening so the anger was fresh.  Also, further supported later on when there is a passing comment about how the maid hung herself by her own braid, committing suicide and in theory redeeming her lost honor by injuring her mistress.
>
> I can try to find the exact line if you’re interested.
>
> Tashina